# google colab error importing externe file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i am using google colab to do data analysis with python. I want to import a file containing functions that I am using. The file describe_csv is in the current directory.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sample_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/TP_flignt'
from describe_csv import *  # charge describe_csv.py by chunk de 10 000 (10**4)
describe_csv(sample_dir+"flights.csv", delimiter=',')
```

I have this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2e41764beaec> in <module>()
----> 1 from describe_csv import *  # charge le fichier describe_csv.py par chunk de 10 000 (10**4)
      2 
      3 describe_csv(sample_dir+"flights.csv", delimiter=',')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'describe_csv'
```

Comment: Have you mounted the drive?

Comment: Apparently `describe_csv.py` is not in the current directory. Make sure to have it in `'/content/`

Comment: Does  `from .describe_csv import *` fix the issue? Added a period before `describe_csv`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My crrent directory is dt='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/TP_flignt/describe_csv.py'

Comment: this is the same in which I have the csv file and the file describe_csv:                                                                                           
                         sample_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/TP_flignt'
       dt='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/TP_flignt/describe_csv.py'